# Amplitude changes in frequency modulation

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, radio

What would happen if the amplitude of the carrier wave in FM waves was changed? Would the signal just be stronger or would radios made for a normal amplitude not be able to decipher the signal?

From what I've learnt in physics it would just make a wave with jibberish once un-modulated.

Comment: As a guess I would say it would not course much difference to radios. Attenuation due to e.g. walls, glass, air etc will decrease the amplitude of the wave anyway. And most radios work indoors and out.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Presumably the OP means modulations in amplitude on timescales comparable with the bandwidth of the signal the FM radio is transmitting, which are unlikely to have a trivial effect. user30646 should clarify what they mean, though.